# Как вывести 4 операнда через XOR?

Tags: php

Как работает оператор xor? В каких случаях он возвращает значение true, в каких – false? 
Помогите написать скрипт который выводит  значения операций со всеми возможными вариантами операндов (4 варианта).
Чему равно $a xor $a для любых значений $a?

Comment: @dimkachel, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: **XOR любит различия**:  `true XOR false = TRUE`, а одинаковым значениям XOR ставит 0 или FALSE.

Скрипт со всеми возможными вариантами вы и сами напишете, я не сомневаюсь. Или разберитесь, как работает мой [макаронный криптокод](http://ideone.com/y10XJo):

    for($i=3;;$i--){
      printf("%b XOR %b = %b".PHP_EOL, ($i&2)>>1, $i&1, ($i&2)>>1^$i&1);
      if(!$i) break;
    }

Comment: @Sergiks, судя по метке php

> В каких случаях он возвращает значение true, в каких – false?

требуется xor из разряда булевых (^), а не побитовых операций (и тогда тем более непонятно, почему здесь висит этот вопрос).

Answer (score 1):

[link text](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D1%EB%EE%E6%E5%ED%E8%E5_%EF%EE_%EC%EE%E4%F3%EB%FE_2#.D0.A1.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B9.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2.D0.B0)

В вики есть все значения таблицы истинности. Возвращает 0 в том случае если один из операндов 0 или оба операнда равны. Тоесть $a xor $a = 0